# Find Taylor series of function around $x=0$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm trying to calculate the Taylor serie around $x=0$ of the function

$$f(x)=\int\limits_0^xe^{-t^2}dt$$

I tried to use the fundamental theorem of calculus, but I'm still stuck.

Comment: What is it that you find difficult? We have $f(0)=0$, and $f'(x)=e^{-t^2}$.

Comment: @Arthur I would say $f'(x)=e^{-x^2}$

Comment: @Arthur I know that but I can't find the explicit expansion, i.e., an expression for the ith term of the sum

Comment: @georg you're right. I was four seconds too late to do anything about it, though.

Answer (score 6):

HINT:

Write $$e^{-t^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nt^{2n}}{n!}$$

and integrate the series term by term.

Comment: If you want to be really sure of your answer, don't forget to check that changing the order of summation and integration doesn't change the result! In this case, you can check using the dominated convergence theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). If you're not used to this, it may take you some time to figure out how the dominated convergence theorem should be applied, but it will become second nature if you practice it enough.

Comment: @vectornaut First note that this post is a HINT only.  Second, I am familiar with DC.  Third, as you know, a power series converges uniformly within its radius of convergence and term by term integration is permissable.

Comment: My comment was directed at the OP. I thought it was important to mention this subtlety because a reasonable person might use the hint without noticing the subtlety—or, worse, conclude from the hint that interchanging summation and integration is always trivial.

Comment: @vectornaut In that case, a +1 for the comment.

Comment: Sorry about the misdirected "you"; I'll be more careful about that in the future.

Comment: @vectornaut Please no worry.  Your commen is indeed very useful and important here.  And I gave your comment a +1.

Answer (score 1):

By following Dr.MV's method a result is developed quickly and is of the form
\begin{align}
f(x) = \int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^{2}} \, dt = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} \, x^{2n+1}}{n! \, (2n+1)}.
\end{align}
An alternate process is to use the Leibniz rule of differentiation of integrals for which
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= e^{-x^2} \\
f''(x) &= - 2 x \, e^{-x^2} \\
f'''(x) &= (4 x^2 - 2) \, e^{-x^2} \\
\cdots &= \cdots \\
f^{(n+1)}(x) &= (-1)^{n} \, H_{n}(x) \, e^{-x^2}
\end{align}
where $H_{m}(x)$ are the Hermite polynomials. Since $H_{2n+1}(0) = 0$ then
$$f^{(2m+1)}(0) = H_{2m}(0) = \frac{(-1)^{m} \, (2m)!}{m!} $$
for which
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f^{(n)}(0) \, \frac{x^{n}}{n!} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f^{(2n+1)}(0) \, \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} \, x^{2n+1}}{n! \, (2n+1)}
\end{align}
which is the same as the faster method.

Comment: Now that was solid!  A big +1.

Comment: @Dr.MV I'm trying to do these answers like this other guy that demonstrates well formed answers. That great demonstrator's name is....Dr.MV.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks. That made my weekend!!